# React Hook useEffect issue with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am using useState which has 2 array imageList and videoList and then in useEffect hook i am using forEach on data then if type is image then push to item to image .
But at last i am not getting imagelist or video list of array.

```
const [list, setDataType] = useState({imageList:[], videoList:[] });
  useEffect (()=>{
    //data is list of array
      dataList.forEach(item =>{

       if(!item.images)  {
         setDataType({...list, imageList:item})
       } 
       else if (item.images[0].type === "video/mp4")
       {
        setDataType({...list, videoList :item})
       }
       else if((item.images[0].type === "images/gpeg")
       {
          setDataType({...list, imageList:item})
       }
      })
  },);
```

Here type check is working correctly but at last i get last fetch data only which can be videolist or imageList
In last i should get list of all imageList whose type is image and same video list whose type is video

Comment: Don't call a `setState` constantly inside a loop, build your state then set it.

Comment: Yeah you can extract all the images and videos in two differnt arrays and then make one call to setState to persist it. Its not an efficient solution to be calling setState in a loop as you are doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a proper way to call setState in a loop. Below is an attempted solution using array method filter to functionally construct the list.

```
const [list, setDataType] = useState({ imageList: [], videoList: [] });
useEffect(() => {
    let videos = dataList.filter(item => item.images[0].type === "video/mp4")
    let images = dataList.filter(item => item.images[0].type === "images/gpeg")
    setDataType({imageList: images, videoList: videos})
}, []);
```

Comment: worked but useEffect goes in infinite loop
 "index.js:1 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render

Comment: did you add the empty array []  dependency at the end of the useEffect?

Comment: @KUMARSUBHAM you could do this also: `[dataList]`

Comment: Yeah That is if you want to re-run the effect each time the datalist array changes. :thumbsup:

Answer (score 0):

Avoid set state inside a loop. On each setState, React will re-render the component. So recommended to prepare your state first and then update the state.

```
const [list, setDataType] = useState({imageList:[], videoList:[] });
  useEffect (() =>{
      let newState = {imageList:[], videoList:[] };
      dataList.forEach(item =>{

            if(!item.images)  {
                newState.imageList.push(item);
            } else if (item.images[0].type === "video/mp4") {
                newState.videoList.push(item);
            } else if((item.images[0].type === "images/gpeg") {
                newState.imageList.push(item);
            }
      });
      setDataType(prevState => {
        return {
            imageList: newState.imageList, 
            videoList: newState.videoList 
        }
     });
},[]);
```

Comment: In this line setDataType( preState => {...preState, imageList:item}) is saying wrong format

Comment: it is going in infinite loop as

Comment: this can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

Comment: thank you sohail it worked .. i saw ur website its awesome ,

Comment: Thank you @Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you don't want to be calling setState constantly inside your loop.  Build the state up and then set it.

Two filters might work for you here..

eg.

```
const [list, setDataType] = useState({imageList:[], videoList:[] });
  useEffect (()=>{
    //data is list of array
    setDataType({
      videoList: dataList.filter(item => item.images[0].type === 'video/mp4'),
      imageList: dataList.filter(item => item.images[0].type === 'images/gpeg')
    });
  },);
```

Comment: only video list is getting data and also useEffect is doing in infinite loop

Comment: Yes, useEffect has no dependency..  for this try -> `}, []);`  Also did you mean `image/jpeg` ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `useEffect` & `useState` hooks for data transformation, which is not part of an asynchronous flow.

This case is better handled with `useMemo`. When the `datalist` changes, `useMemo` will produce the `list`, and if it doesn't change, the memoized value would be used. In addition, it won't cause an infinite loop, because it won't cause a rerender while listening to its own state.

To create `list`, use a Map that will hold the mime-types and their respective types. Reduce the array of items, and according to the type you get from the Map, push them in the `images` or `videos` sub-arrays.

```
/** external code (not in the hook) **/
const types = new Map([['video/mp4', 'video'], ['images/gpeg', 'image']])

const getListType = ({ type }) => types.has(type) ? 
  `${types.get(type)}List` : null

/** hook code **/
const list = useMemo(() => dataList.reduce((r, item) => {
  const list = getListType(item.images[0])

  is(list) r[list].push(item)

  return r;
}, { imageList:[], videoList:[] }), [dataList])
```